# How do I achieve this sort of graph wireframe effect in my 3D objects? Blender 2.8

Tags: animation, materials, wireframe

I want to achieve this cool translucent see-through effect with a graph wireframe background in my 3D objects as shown in the images below. How do I do this?

I have regular low poly objects with materials. This effect comes in really handy when you want to explain the architecture of an opaque object.

So, for an object I need to have both the effects. The regular opaque material design look & the translucent see through look;

I am using Blender 2.8

The screenshots are from a youtube channel called the Real Engineering

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do a google search for [Freestyle](https://www.google.com/search?q=blender%20freestyle&oq=blender%20freestyle&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.7733j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 1):

Try <strike>a Translucent Shader</strike> any shader, lol, with the **blend mode (if you're using Eevee) set to additive**.  The Principled shader works well : )  GL OP